# Same Title on two different post type with single custom taxonomy

Tags: plugins, php, post-meta, seo

I have a custom taxonomy "Store" assigned to two post types : default "Post" type and second "Coupons"

for all "Post" of ebay : my links is - `http://domain.com/store/ebay/`
and all "Coupons" of ebay : my links is - `http://domain.com/coupons/store/ebay/`

my issue is both page have same meta title and description.

can your please tell me how can i get both pages with different meta title and description.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using a third party plugin. Most SEO Plugins let you manually set the Title and Description of the page independent from the Title and Slug of the post. The Slug itself is unique over the place to avoid duplication.

One Plugin I know which is doing this good and works well in other aspects is [Yoast SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/).